# How comes .array() doesn't work on ByteBuffers returned from map'ed FileChannels?

Tags: java, bytebuffer, memory-mapping

I'm doing memory-mapped IO in Java.  The FileChannel class allows you to map a ByteBuffer to a particular part of a file. I'm doing that with a file opened read only.

The problem I am having is that I'm getting an exception when I attempt to call the .array() method on the resulting ByteBuffer. Perhaps that's because the .array() returns a byte[] array, and I really want a finalized byte array?

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is about the [`FileChannel.map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)) method which can map a file to memory which can be accessed by a [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).

In the documentation for the `FileChannel.map` method, if the file is mapped as read-only, the any attempt to modify the buffer will result in a [`ReadOnlyBufferException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ReadOnlyBufferException.html):

> A region of a file may be mapped into
>   memory in one of three modes:
>
> - Read-only: Any attempt to modify
>     the resulting buffer will cause a
>     `ReadOnlyBufferException` to be thrown.
>     (`MapMode.READ_ONLY`)

In terms of the exceptions thrown by the [`ByteBuffer.array`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array()) method, there are two types of exceptions which are thrown depending on the reason for the problem:

> Throws:
>
> - `ReadOnlyBufferException` - If this buffer is backed by an array but is read-only
> - `UnsupportedOperationException` - If this buffer is not backed by an accessible array

Although the exception being thrown is not mentioned in the question, perhaps the file being read-only is causing the [`ReadOnlyBufferException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ReadOnlyBufferException.html) to be thrown by the `array` method.

Also, it should also be mentioned that the [`ByteBuffer.array`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array()) method is an optional operation:

> Returns the byte array that backs this
>   buffer  (optional operation).

To be sure that the `array` method will return a `byte[]` that can be used, invoke the `hasArray` method as suggested in the documentation for the `array` method:

> Invoke the [`hasArray`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#hasArray()) method before
>   invoking this method in order to
>   ensure that this buffer has an
>   accessible backing array.

Comment: Of course, arrays may get moved around in memory and have a header, which doesn't fit well with memory mapped files or direct allocated buffers.

Comment: This does answer the question, but it's not the answer I wanted. POSIX mmap() has no problem memory-mapping read-only. java should do that too.